# Rspecのmodelテストで、user_id: nil, post_id: nilになってしまう。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

現在railsでRspecテストを作成中です。
**factory_bot_rails**のGemを使用しています。
おそらくfactory_bot_railsを使用しての、データの作成方法に間違いがあると思われるんですが、
今回の場合、どうすれば**postとuser**、そして**commentとpostとuser**を紐付ける事が出来るのでしょうか？
ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

```
[factories/posts.rb]
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    association :user
    img { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/img/people.jpg")) }

    trait :created_at_5_years_ago do
      created_at { 5.year.ago }
    end

    trait :created_at_1_year_ago do
      created_at { 1.year.ago }
    end

    trait :created_at_1_week_ago do
      created_at { 1.week.ago }
    end

    trait :created_at_1_day_ago do
      created_at { 1.day.ago }
    end
  end
end

[models/post_spec.rb]
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryBot.build(:post)).to be_valid
  end
end

下記エラー内容
expected #<Post id: nil, img: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Userを入力してください
```

```
[factories/comments.rb]
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :comment do
    association :user
    association :post
    content { "Comment コメント" }
  end
end

[models/comment_spec.rb]
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Comment, type: :model do
  it "has a valid comment" do
    expect(FactoryBot.build(:comment)).to be_valid
  end
end

下記エラー内容
expected #<Comment id: nil, content: "Comment コメント", user_id: nil, post_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Userを入力してください, Postを入力してください
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FactoryBotにおいて、associationには`strategy`オプションが渡せます。
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#build-strategies-1
`strategy: :create`を指定すれば`Post`を`build`したタイミングで`user`が作られます。

---

余談ながら、`build`したタイミングで`valid`かどうかを判定することはあまり一般的ではありません。
もしファクトリ自体が有効であるかどうかを検証したいのであれば、`.lint`メソッドが使えます。
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories